# Sum by Date Laravel Datatables

Tags: php, laravel, date, datatables, sum

I have a problem while grouping my Datatable in Laravel 8,

Here is the data,

```
Table: cash_in
Date        Code    Amount
2020-12-01  0001    100
2020-12-01  0001    200
2020-12-01  0002    300
2020-12-01  0002    400
2020-12-02  0001    500
2020-12-02  0002    600
2020-12-02  0002    700
```

I want to group by and sum the code 0001 and code 0002 based on the date.

```
Date        0001    0002
2020-12-01  300     700
2020-12-02  500     1300
```

Kindly help me to bring up this solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the queries you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```php
$data = [
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-01",
        "Code" => "0001",
        "Amount" => "100",
    ],
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-01",
        "Code" => "0001",
        "Amount" => "200",
    ],
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-01",
        "Code" => "0002",
        "Amount" => "300",
    ],
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-01",
        "Code" => "0002",
        "Amount" => "400",
    ],
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-02",
        "Code" => "0001",
        "Amount" => "500",
    ],
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-02",
        "Code" => "0002",
        "Amount" => "500",
    ],
    [
        "Date" => "2020-12-02",
        "Code" => "0002",
        "Amount" => "700",
    ]
];

$data = collect($data);
$newData = $data->groupBy('Date')->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
        "date" => $key,
        "total" => $item->sum('Amount'),
        "code"=>$item[0]['Code'],
    ];
})->values();
return $newData;
```

Comment: hi, there is still a problem that is: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::map()

Comment: it is database.? instances i thought it is a collection , first get all data by `Model::all()` store in a variable then apply my code